# Filter the DBTables value in windows form based on user typed text

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application, windows-forms-designer

I am currently working on filtering a list of records based on user typed text. I am getting duplicates records as I type the next character.

```
IList<DBTables> listOne = new List<DBTables>();
        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.listBox1.DataSource = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
        {
            string toFind = textBox2.Text;
            //listone.name is dataName
            foreach (DBTables s in listOne)
            {
                
                string dataName = s.Name;

                if (dataName.Contains(toFind))
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(dataName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to display all list on listbox1 that contain text in textbox2

```
list on listbox1:
        USA
        Canada
        Can
        UK
        China
        Japan

    If I type 'ca' in textbox2 : Current output I get in listbox1:
    Canada
    Can
    Canada
    Can

    Output I want:
    Canada
    Can
```

Comment: What is `DBTables`? Why do you set `this.listBox1.DataSource = null;` when you plan on adding items one by one to the ListBox after? Note that you can filter your List with a [`Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) condition and set the datasource of the Control using the resulting collection.

Comment: Why did you tag `console-application` and `winforms`? Are you showing a Form in a Console app?

Comment: Do not add/remove items to the list. Use data-binding to a list which supports filtering. Or just data binding to list and reset bindings after changing the list.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any `listBox1.Items.Clear()` instruction to remove the existing items in the list. If you don't clear the list items, the list will include results of all earlier searches.

Add this after `string toFind = textBox2.Text;` and before the `foreach` loop which adds new entries to the list:

```
listBox1.Items.Clear(); // remove any existing items in list
```

FYI: Since you've only provided a code snippet we don't know what the rest of the code is doing, so any answers are guesswork. To get better answers in future, extract the logic that's not working for you into a separate & complete test application which reproduces your problem.  Then post the code for the test application. Remove any logic that is specific to your application, eg replace `List<DBTables>` with a `List<string>`, provided that your problem is still reproduced.